# Modifying a column value depending on other column value for all the rows

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a teradata table. Now I need to add a column, say, Flag and insert values into the Flag column which will depend on  say, Sales. Flag=1 if Sales greater than x or Flag=0.
Here is the structure of Table at present

```
Sales    Date 
 10    11/11/1987
 20    12/13/1987
```

I want it like the following way

```
Sale    Date       Flag
 10   11/11/1987    0
 20   12/13/1987    1
```

I tried to look for such problems on the forums but couldn't find any. Excuse if you find any duplicate problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to use here is a `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE teradata_table
SET flag = CASE WHEN sales > 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Answer (score 2):

after adding the column, do the update statement

```
Update <table>
set Flag = case when Sale<=10 then 0 
                else 1
           end
```

Comment: oooh, snap. Beat me by 42 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE
( FLAG NUMBER(1) );

UPDATE MYTABLE SET FLAG = 1 WHERE SALE >= 10;
```

Comment: Let's say I want something like Flag=1 when Sales is even and Flag=0 otherwise. I can do it by running two update statements. Can't it be done in one statement? Is case-when useful in this case?

Comment: Even and Odd is just an example case. I could be given to work on different type of cases depending on my sales, quantity, (the columns I assumed not important to specify here). I just need a generalized approach.

Comment: Case .. When would be the best way to handle that sort of scenario.